# Получение и парсинг данных из более чем одного источника

Tags: php, парсер

Я написал скрипт который получает данные, парсит их и  выводит нужную информацию на локальной web-странице в браузере через n количество секунд. Но существует существенный недостаток. Скрипт получает данные с нескольких источников и для каждого источника я открываю отдельное окно в браузере и там выполняется скрипт и выводится информация.

*Как реализовать так, чтобы получать/парсить данные в одном скрипте?*
Данные приходят в виде `Json` с одного url http://api.site.ru/?id=, где отличается только по id(1, 2, 3).
Вот скрипт который выполняет обработку и парсит данные по условию:

```
$ID = "1";

function prepareBaseData( $items ) {
    $res = array();
    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        $res[$item['def']] = $item;
    }
    return $res;
}


$floatValues = array(
    654466, 6546444, 998678, 885467
); // уcловия для парсинга

//База для сравнения
$schema_json = file_get_contents( 'base_items030817.json' );
$schema_data = json_decode( $schema_json, true );

$s_array = $schema_data['res']['it']; // Вложеность для парсинга c локальной базы

$itemBase = prepareBaseData( $s_array );

$b_json = file_get_contents( ' http://api.site.ru/?id='.$ID );
$b_data = json_decode( $b_json, true );

$items_array  = $b_data['res']['it']; // вложенность для поиска в полученных данных

$res = array();

foreach ( $items_array as $item )
{
    if ( !isset( $itemBase[$item['def']] ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    $currBaseItem = $itemBase[$item['def']];

    if ( !isset( $item['attr'] ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach($item['attr'] as $attr ) {
        if ( ( isset( $attr['fl_value'] ) && in_array( $attr['fl_value'], $floatValues ) ))
        {
            $res[] = array(
                'qual' => $item['qual'],
                'img_url' => $currBaseItem['img_url'],
                'name' => $currBaseItem['name'],
                'fl_value' => $attr['fl_value'],
                'def' => $attr['def']
            );
        }
    }
}

foreach( $res as $data ){
    echo sprintf( '<li style="border-color:%s"><div style="background-image:url(%s);" class="img"><p class = "name">%s</p><span class="paint" style="background: url(%s);"></span><span class="hs" style="background: url(%s);"></span></div></li>', $data['qual'], $data['img_url'], $data['lvl'], $data['name'], $data['fl_value'], $data['def'] );
}
```

Я так понимаю нужно сделать массив:
`$IDs = array(1, 2, 3);`
проходить его циклом, подставляя в ссылку и данные записывать, в так называемый, "промежуточный" массив и уже этот массив парсить.

Как правильно реализовать это на практике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из решений в лоб, заменить:

```
$b_json = file_get_contents( ' http://api.site.ru/?id='.$ID );
$b_data = json_decode( $b_json, true );

$items_array  = $b_data['res']['it'];
```

на

```
$items_array = [];
$ids = [1,2,3];
foreach($ids as $id){
    $b_data = json_decode(@file_get_contents('http://api.site.ru/?id='.$id), true);
    if($b_data){
        $items_array  = array_merge($items_array, $b_data['res']['it']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда уже лучше весь код поместить в цикл, иначе дальнейшая его работа, будет идти уже с id 3

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов дальнейший код не использует $ID, не вижу смысла заталкивать все под одно

Comment: Код дальше, будет работать с последним вариантом парса, так что, нет...

Comment: @Bookin Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' у меня PHP 5.3.27

Comment: @excellproj ваша версия PHP не поддерживает короткий синтаксис для массивов, замените `[]` на `array()`

Comment: @Bookin это первое, что я сделал. Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_mearge()

Comment: @excellproj - array_merge, вечно что то эту `а` пихаю

Comment: @Bookin так как array_merge сливает два массива, то первый аргумент не масив в вашем варианте: Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: @excellproj я вам привел пример, думаю вставить `$items_array=array();` перед циклом, вы вполне способны самостоятельно

Comment: @bookin согласен. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Что мешает вам, все реализовать в одном скрипте? Вот моя реализация, я просто пропускаю через цикл весь скрипт парса, каждый раз парс новое значения с Id, взятым из массива.

```
$ID = "1";

function prepareBaseData( $items ) {
$res = array();
foreach( $items as $item ) {
    $res[$item['def']] = $item;
}
return $res;
}


 $floatValues = array(
     654466, 6546444, 998678, 885467
 ); // уcловия для парсинга

 //База для сравнения
 $schema_json = file_get_contents( 'base_items030817.json' );
 $schema_data = json_decode( $schema_json, true );

  $s_array = $schema_data['res']['it']; // Вложеность для парсинга c локальной базы

 $itemBase = prepareBaseData( $s_array );
 $ids = [1, 2, 3];

foreach($ids as $id){ 
    $b_json = file_get_contents( ' http://api.site.ru/?id='.$id);
    $b_data = json_decode( $b_json, true );

    $items_array  = $b_data['res']['it']; // вложенность для поиска в полученных данных

$res = array();

foreach ( $items_array as $item )
{
if ( !isset( $itemBase[$item['def']] ) ) {
    continue;
}

$currBaseItem = $itemBase[$item['def']];

if ( !isset( $item['attr'] ) ) {
    continue;
}

foreach($item['attr'] as $attr ) {
    if ( ( isset( $attr['fl_value'] ) && in_array( $attr['fl_value'], $floatValues ) ))
    {
        $res[] = array(
            'qual' => $item['qual'],
            'img_url' => $currBaseItem['img_url'],
            'name' => $currBaseItem['name'],
            'fl_value' => $attr['fl_value'],
            'def' => $attr['def']
        );
    }
   }
 }

 foreach( $res as $data ){
   echo sprintf( '<li style="border-color:%s"><div       style="background-image:url(%s);" class="img"><p class = "name">%s</p><span class="paint" style="background: url(%s);">.</span><span class="hs" style="background: url(%s);"></span></div></li>', $data['qual'], $data['img_url'], $data['lvl'],  $data['name'], $data['fl_value'], $data['def'] );
 }
 }
```

Comment: код хотя бы отформатируйте

Comment: У меня нет в данный момент возможности форматировать код, я с телефона.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов так как нужно выводить отпарсенные данные отновременно со всех источников, то я делал реализацию в одном скрипте, где было file_get_contents и цыкл на каждый источник и это сильно тормозило выполнение и выглядело ужасно